# how to assign integer value + string value in c# linq query for same column

Tags: c#, linq

String + Int + String is not working, when i assign the values to string column 
 -> I Need the **Name** column value like :

> AS Project Employee ID: 1878 Employee Name: Kevin dominic..

```
select new
        {
            ID = AS_ProjectHeader.ID,
            PartyID = AS_ProjectHeader.PartyID,
            Name = AS_ProjectHeader.Name + "  Employee ID: " + AS_ProjectHeader.EmployeeID + " Employee Name:" + AS_ProjectHeader.PAYE_Employee.Forenames + " " + AS_ProjectHeader.PAYE_Employee.Surname,
            ClientName = AS_ProjectHeader.AS_PartyList.Name,
            StartDate = AS_ProjectHeader.StartDate,
            EndDate = AS_ProjectHeader.EndDate,

        });
```

EDIT: Additional information:

If i use convert to string for the integer value i get this error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: i don't think that you can do it every field should contain only 1 word/value

Comment: Try it with String.Format()

Comment: `... is not working` <= Please be more specific, include any exception and its details in your question. See also [ask] and please include an [mcve].

Comment: "String + Int + String is not working," usually it is working. it results in a concatenated string

Comment: Igor .. I need the string + int + string values to be assigned to a string variable

Comment: what is the output that you get? I think we got that point of what you need, you just did not describe what you really get when running your code.

Comment: Mong Zhu -- If i use convert to string for the integer value i get this error ---> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: `Igor .. I need the string + int + string values to be assigned to a string variable` <= No, I get that. What you did not provide though was what **is** happening. Simply stating "not working" could mean anything. Your computer could have exploded for all I know. We can't see your code, we can't see your output, and we are not  mind readers. You have to be more specific. As mentioned please include the Exception (*from the original line of code*) and all its details OR describe what does occur if there is no exception.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, next time please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42947555/edit) button below your post, to add further information to your post

Comment: Upgrade your EF version.

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: Mong Zhu .. version 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleae Use *SqlFunctions.StringConvert* ,it will work

Name = PSC_ProjectHeader.Name + "  Employee ID: " + **SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)PSC_ProjectHeader.EmployeeID)**
                            + " Employee Name:" + PSC_ProjectHeader.PAYE_Employee.Forenames + " " + PSC_ProjectHeader.PAYE_Employee.Surname,

Comment: Thanks Durai.. Let me try this

Comment: Working fine? `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` produces strings padded left with spaces up to length 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `.ToString()`
but be-careful you could't use control like `textBox1.Text` inside `Linq` query

Comment: If i use convert to string for the integer value i get this error ---> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store

Comment: So, try to declare new string variable before `Linq` query then assign `var_name.ToString();` then use `var_name` in your `Linq` query

Comment: let me try Ahmend

Comment: Not working.. its works if the combination as string + Int but when it comes to String + int + string not working results in error as system.string method failed.

Answer (score 0):

***This following is relevent only if using EF version older than 6.1***

Linq-To-Entities really doesn't support `ToString`.

You have to materialize the query first (`ToList()`) and then select what you want.

So let say that `query` is what you have until the select.

```
query.ToList().Select(AS_ProjectHeader =>
{
    ID = AS_ProjectHeader.ID,
    PartyID = AS_ProjectHeader.PartyID,
    Name = AS_ProjectHeader.Name 
           + "  Employee ID: " + AS_ProjectHeader.EmployeeID 
           + " Employee Name:" + AS_ProjectHeader.PAYE_Employee.Forenames + " " 
                               + AS_ProjectHeader.PAYE_Employee.Surname,
    ClientName = AS_ProjectHeader.AS_PartyList.Name,
    StartDate = AS_ProjectHeader.StartDate,
    EndDate = AS_ProjectHeader.EndDate,
}
```

Comment: *Linq-To-Entities really doesn't support ToString*. It does as of v6.1.